# How to extract the UI label texts using selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

HTML is as follows :

```html
<div id="field-container" class="field-container center">
  <form id="param-list" class="ui form">
    <div>
      <div class="field-group"><label class="input-label" data-tooltip="Australia, Hello" data-position="right center">Beta</label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="ui input"><input id="11" value="123" type="text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field-group"><label class="input-label" data-tooltip="Australia, USA" data-position="right center">Carbon Reduction</label>
        <div class="field">
          <div class="ui input"><input id="12" value="" type="text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have above html for my webUI, i am trying to read the all the fields inside (id="param-list") and get the Name which are Beta and Carbon Reduction and also the data for "data-tooltip". Below is what i am trying to do, but i am not able to get it back.

```
   public static List<string> GetFieldsName()
        {
            List<string> expected = new List<string>();
            IWebElement elament = driver.FindElement(container);  //container = By.Id("param-list");
            IList<IWebElement> fieldNames = elament.FindElements(FiledName); //By.ClassName("field");
            foreach (IWebElement fieldname in fieldNames)
            {
                IList<IWebElement> names = fieldname.FindElements(Inputlable); //By.ClassName("input");
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    expected.Add(name.GetAttribute("tooltip"));

                }
            }
            return expected;
        }
```

when i do this all i get back is NULL and not sure how to select Name which is **Beta** and **Carbon Reduction** from above Html.

Comment: Your question does not have clarity on what you need to do. From what i understand is you want to get the label value displayed for each label element inside your form i.e. you should get 'Beta' and 'Carbon Reduction'....you can get all labels using css selector : 'form[id='param-list'] label' ...This will give a collection with two labels...Now you can call element.Text to get the values of labels.

Comment: You can also get label elements using selector 'label.input-label'...If you want to get data-tooltip value for each label , you can call element.GetAttribute('data-tooltip')

Comment: Thanks Nish26, based on your suggestion i changed my code to get the lable name and works fine..

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the UI `<label>` *texts* you can use either of the following solutions:

```
public static List<string> GetFieldsName()
{
    List<string> expected = new List<string>();
    IList<IWebElement> labelNames = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='field-container center' and @id='field-container']//div[@class='field-group']/label[@class='input-label']"));
    foreach (IWebElement labelName in labelNames)
    {
        expected.Add(labelName.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }
    return expected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below will return you tooltips, if you need both text and tooltip use double array or dictionary

```
public static List<string> GetFieldsName()
{
    List<string> expected = new List<string>();
    IList<IWebElement> labels = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("form#param-list label[data-tooltip]"));
    foreach (IWebElement label in labels)
    {
        expected.Add(label.GetAttribute("data-tooltip"));
        //To get text("Carbon Reduction",...) use label.GetText()
    }
    return expected;
}
```